# How java projects are deployed in client location

Tags: java

Can any one out there can explain how java projects that are made are deployed in client location and how the server is changed i.e from development server to the web logic server, how the codes are secured from client members can  access any one explain

Comment: It depends on the Web Server you are using. So what is the web server you are using? please specify every details.

Comment: It depends on so many things that this question is too broad.